# My main file can't find another file I created that I imported into the main file

Tags: go

I have the following file structure:

```
- project/
  - src/
    - main/
      - main.go
    - viewmodels/
      - home.go
  - public/
```

My project is found in:
`~/go/src/`

When I attempt to run my main file it throws the error:

```
src/main/main.go:10:2: cannot find package "viewmodels" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.3/libexec/src/viewmodels (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/nicholasrucci/go/src/viewmodels (from $GOPATH)
```

It looks like main is looking for `package viewmodels` in the wrong location. From my understanding, after reading [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) and the previous programs would run fine, my configuration is set up correctly, but obviously something is wrong.

Go related configurations from **.zshrc**:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Snippet of **main.go**:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
    "viewmodels"
)
```

Snippet of **home.go**:

```
package viewmodels

import ()
```

Any direction for what is going on and how I can fix this issue would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the full package name for the import path: `"project/src/viewmodels"` in this case, assuming project is under `/Users/nicholasrucci/go/src`, but I would structure your project folder differently (no src folder for example)

Alternatively you could set your GOPATH to the fully qualified path to your project folder, which would then allow your main.go to `import "viewmodels"` as you have it.

Comment: That definitely did the trick. I also wasn't aware that a GOPATH could be set per project. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do it that way, all your `go get` dependencies will be installed under your project/src folder.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me:

**src/main/main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "viewmodels"
)

func main() {
    viewmodels.Something()
}
```

**src/viewmodels/home.go**

```
package viewmodels

import ()

func Something() {

}
```

I'm guessing it is your env variables.